# Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution Configuration Manager

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

When ever I attempt to debug an Android app that is the error I receive. The APK deploys and can be run manually but I cant ever debug the application .

Not sure what else to try. I have validated the that the android application is set to deploy(which works because the apk is on the device) but I cant ever debug the code.

EDIT: Adding my deployment config
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual-Studio, right click your `Solution` --> `Configuration Manager` --> Check the `Deploy` option in the `xxx.Android Project`.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Already checked that before posting here. the apk IS being deployed but VS2019/Xamarin  cant seem to see it on the device. Its almost like there is a mismatch between the package name and what VS2019 is looking for....

Comment: Did you solved it? Maybe you can try delete bin/obj, then clean and rebuild again.

Comment: I am unable to solve this issue, I have cleaned/rebuilt numerous times

Comment: Can you install it if you delete the app which already installed on your device? Can you share the device log?

Comment: I think there might a be a miscommunication, the apk is deploying but the debugger cant start the apk or find it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean by the debugger cant start the apk or find it ? You mean you can't see any information in the output window in VS? Or a breakpoint won't work?